# Date Pipe Formatting

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

Currently my dates are showing as Sep/04/2018. I am curious how to get the date to show as Sep-04-2018. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
export class DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
public transform(value: string): number {
    if (!value) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Date.parse(value.replace(/\//g, ' '));
}}
```

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe? You don't need a custom pipe for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular Date Pipe for that.

Here today is a date object.

*.html file

```
<div>{{ today | date : ' MMM-dd-yyyy ' }}</div>
```

*.ts file

```js
today: Date = new Date();
```